# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react while passing through props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am building simple react application it showing map is undefine please resolve this error it might help a lot
**child code**

```
 const classes = useStyles()
    const {qnsObject,answersList} = props.value
    
    console.log(qnsObject,answersList)
return (
       
        qnsObject.map((content,index) =>{
            let count = content.tags.split(',')
            return (
                <div className = {classes.homeRecentQns} >
                <div className ={classes.homeRecentQnsParent}>
                    <div className = {classes.avatar_parent}>
                     <div className ={classes.avatar}>
                        <Avatar alt='tfds' src ={content.profile_img} className 
               = {classes.small}>{content.firstName[0].toUpperCase()}</Avatar>
                     </div>
                     <div className ={classes.voted_parent}>
                         <ArrowDropUpTwoToneIcon className = 
               {classes.voted_up}/>
                         <p>125</p>
                        <ArrowDropDownTwoToneIcon className = 
                  {classes.voted_down}/>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className ={classes.recentQns_parent}>
                        <div className = {classes.recentQns_tags_parent}>
                          <p className = {classes.recentQns_name}> 
                  {content.firstName} {content.lastName}</p>
                          <p className = {classes.recentQns_occupation}> 
                     {content.currentWorking}</p>
                          <p className = {classes.recentQns_askedIn}><b 
                       className = {classes.recentQns_askedIn_bold}>Asked in: 
                       </b>{content.posted_date}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className ={classes.recentQns_desc}>
                            <p className ={classes.recentQns_title}> 
                            {content.qnsTitle}</p>
                            <p className ={classes.recentQns_answers}>
                            {ReactHtmlParser(content.Question_body)}
                           </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className ={classes.recentQns_topic_tags}>
                        {content.tags.split(',').map(chip =>{
                           return <> <Chip   label={chip} variant="filled" 
                       color="primary" size="small" icon= 
                        {<LocalOfferTwoToneIcon />} /></>
                        })}                                               
                        </div>
                        <div className ={classes.recentQns_views_parent}>
                                <div className = {classes.popular_desc_view}>
                                    <QuestionAnswerIcon className = 
                                   {classes.views_icon}/>
                                    <div className = {classes.p}> 
                                 {answersList.length} Answers</div>
                                </div>
                                <div className = {classes.popular_desc_view}>
                                    <VisibilityIcon className = 
                                    {classes.views_icon}/>
                                    <div className = {classes.p}>5 views</div>
                                </div>
                         </div>
                        
                       </div>
                     
                 </div>
                
            </div>
            )
        })
               
            )
```

**parent code**

```
 const Auth = useContext(Authapi)
    const [body,setBody] = useState("")
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [dataQns,setDataqns] = useState([])
    const [closeAns, setAns] = React.useState(false);
    let href = window.location.href.split('/')
    console.log(dataQns)
    const classes = useStyles()
    useEffect(() =>{
     
      const get = async () =>{
          const data =  await fetch('/getAnswers/'+href[href.length -1])
          const dataItems = await data.json()
          console.log(dataItems)
          setDataqns(dataItems)
          }
      
          get()
      
   },[dataQns])
```

**this props I passing**
`<ViewPostComponent value = {dataQns}/>`
how to get update when new data is ready to render using hooks please answer to this question
how to update map function when new data getting from server

Answer (score 0):

**map is undefined** means that you have not passed any data to the map() function

Comment: please give solution for this

Comment: map not showing only when refresh the page

Comment: try removing dataQns from the useEffect dependency array at the bottom, you are creating a loop by setting the **setDataqns(dataItems)** and then telling the useEffect to re-run once the dataQns changes value

Comment: what does your console show from the ````console.log(dataItems)````

Comment: an array...an object...what is it showing ? it needs to be an array

Comment: i see the title of the variable is qnsObject...is this an array of objects?

Comment: showing {qnsObject: Array(1), answersList: Array(0)}

Comment: how can i wait for data before passing through props

Comment: the props are updated when the state is change by your useEffect.  **remove .value from props.value in your child component**

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are mapping an empty array or a variable that is not an array.

You can check the length before mapping.

```
{ 
   variable.length > 0 && variable.map((e) => your code )  
}
```

- Update
  Instead of using just a variable, you need to use React State.
  When data is loaded, set the data into the state and everything will work.

Comment: during  start fetching it shows undefine but how to update atter new one data fetched or how to wait for that data before sending to props

Comment: In this case you need to use React State. When the value changes the component will reload.

Comment: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. shows in browser

Comment: You need to load your data in a UseEffect. Sorry for the long time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use content loading before api call

```
{!!dataQns ? (<ViewPostComponent value = {dataQns}/> )  : (<SomeLoadingSvgAnimationComponent>) }
```

Answer (score 0):

{qnsObject && qnsObject.map((content,index)........}

Try this while mapping. Mapping will occur only when qnsObject is an array else it will return null.